# Hashtable vs Dictionary, why are collection types very similiar to each other?

Tags: c#, dictionary

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [.NET HashTable Vs Dictionary - Can the Dictionary be as fast?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089132/net-hashtable-vs-dictionary-can-the-dictionary-be-as-fast)
>   [Which Collection Class to use: Hashtable or Dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433713/which-collection-class-to-use-hashtable-or-dictionary)

What are the benefits of using Hastable over Dictionary?

Comment: Exact Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089132/net-hashtable-vs-dictionary-can-the-dictionary-be-as-fast

Comment: Performance characteristics. API's the same, implementation is different, so different operations are faster with one or the other.

Comment: @Rafe: In what way are the APIs the same? Hashtable is non-generic, Dictionary is generic. I'd say that's a pretty important difference between the two. (There are other differences too - where's TryGetValue on Hashtable? How do each of them behave when fetching a key which doesn't exist?)

Comment: @Jon ah, I see this is a C# question. I had assumed it was a general question, and in most cases (there are always exceptions) mappings have similar APIs (there's usually a protocol or an interface defining what a map should look like) but different performance characteristics.